# How to make click event work with dynamically generated html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, dynamicform

When the **add more** link is clicked, a **div** is dynamically generated that adds an additional text input and a **add more** link. This dynamically inserted **add more** link doesn't respond to click event. Even though each dynamically inserted link has a unique id and the click event uses "delegated" binding through Jquery **on() method**, yet the dynamically inserted link does not work by adding more fields when clicked. Here is a [jsbin](https://jsbin.com/wucekucohi/edit?html,output) and the whole code is below:

**The Javascript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).on("ready", function(){

    return $(".add_people_filter").on("click", function(event){

      event.preventDefault();

      var time = new Date().getTime();
      var dynamicallyCreatedDiv = document.createElement("div");
      dynamicallyCreatedDiv.id = time;

      var peopleFilterContainerDiv = $("#people_filter_container");
      peopleFilterContainerDiv.append(dynamicallyCreatedDiv);
      var getHtmlForDynamicDiv = $(".people_filter").html();
      var theNewDiv = $(dynamicallyCreatedDiv);
      theNewDiv.append(getHtmlForDynamicDiv);

      var AddUniqueIdToLinK = time * 2;
      var x = time * 3;
      $(this).attr('id', AddUniqueIdToLinK);
      theNewDiv.find("a:last").attr('id', x);

      return theNewDiv;
   });
 });
</script>
```

**The html:**

```
<div id="people_filter_container">
  <div class="people_filter"  >
    <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="add name" >
    <a href="#" data-behavior="add_people_filter" class="add_people_filter"> add more</a> 
    <br> <br>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Why are you returning values from the ready function and the click callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it for that :

```
return $("body").on("click",".add_people_filter", function(event)
{
        ...... YOUR CODE      
});
```